# Suggestion of how to create a javascript class

Tags: javascript, class, jquery

I have a Java App with this architecture: Entity + Persistence + Business + REST Services.

I want to create the view layer without JSF, in other words, I want to use only HTML + CSS + JS (JQuery + Ajax).

What is the better way to create a JavaScript class to access the REST services?

```
var Bookmark = function() {
this.id;
this.description;
this.link;
};

Bookmark.prototype._insert = function() {
// here should i put the JQuery Ajax Call?
}; 

Bookmark.prototype._delete = function() {
// here should i put the JQuery Ajax Call?
}

Bookmark.prototype._update = function() {
// here should i put the JQuery Ajax Call?
}

Bookmark.prototype._findById = function() {
// here should i put the JQuery Ajax Call?
}

Bookmark.prototype._findById = function() {
// here should i put the JQuery Ajax Call?
}
```

The above format is acceptable?

Comment: whatever works for you I would say. angular.js already provides support for services using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is ok.  The problem you might encounter is that if your interaction with the server does not fall clearly into the realm of one model object, your model layer is going to get messy.

Why not do what you do on the server, and create a service layer?

```
App.API =  {

     login: function(onSuccess) {....}

     findBook: function(id, onSuccess) {....}


}
```